# How to Open any type of locally stored file in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have many types of file i.e. pdf, xls, xlsx, doc, docx. All these files are stored locally on the external storage, what I want to do is display the file in `WebView` and not open them via any external app, I have tried many different way but none of them are working for locally stored documents. The codes I have tried to open the pdf files are as follows:

My WebView setting

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Tried codes:

1

```
final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(uri.toString(), "", fileType, "utf-8", null);
```

2

```
webView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
```

3

```
webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + uri.toString());
```

Kindly help.

Comment: @JackTheHealer I don't remember much but we used pdf files and opened it via google drive link.